# Input a text into a text field, click a button and get the result on the page (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a skill for the amazon echo (with js and JQuery) but I am a little stuck.
I want to enter 2 things in 2 different text fields on a website. 
This works. `$('#Field1').val("Test Text"); $('#Field2').val("Test Text 2");`

E.g. Field1: Test Text --- Field2: Test Text 2

Then I want to click a button on this Website. This doesn't work and I don't know how to do it.

After pressing the button I want to get the results that show up on the website. Getting the results (when using manual input, so clicking the button by hand) works. 
I hope you guys get me and can help me!

Greetings Fabian

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want to be able to do. Will a human be clicking a button?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No. When you visit the website you can enter a start destination and a stop destination. Then you can click submit and you will get the data when the train leaves, etc... I want this to be automated so iIget the data of the train in the end.

Comment: You are still not being clear. if "you can click submit", then "yes" - a human will click the button, but your comment says "No.".

Comment: A human CAN click the button. But I don't want a human to click the button.

Comment: Ok, you are talking in circles. Please take some time and think about the best way to describe what you want in detail. Then edit your question to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the form.

[HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) works with input types of "button" and "submit".

[HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) submits a form.

jQuery also has a [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method and aliases like `.click()` if you need to trigger specific jQuery events.

You'll need to understand what elements and event listeners the form has and use the appropriate methods. Note that these techniques have caveats and restrictions because of browser compatibility and security risks for the user.

Comment: I have tried this but it said: "click is not a function". I guess it is because I execute it in a separate JavaScript and not on the website itself. Do you know how to make it work anyways?